# What will occur when I apply .take(2) for a Flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I get records from database using  `handleMInfo.listIncompleted()`  with Room,    and   `listIncompleted` returns a `Flow`.

1:  I think Code A will keep runing, and `todo(it)`  will be launched again and again when the records in database changed, right?

2:  I think the whole operation will be cancelled after  `todo(it)`  is only invoked in two times  even if  the records in database changed in Code B,  right?

**Code   A**

```
val listIncompleted = handleMInfo.listIncompleted()        
    
listIncompleted
   .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)           
   .collect { todo(it) }
```

**Code   B**

```
val listIncompleted = handleMInfo.listIncompleted()        
    
listIncompleted
   .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
   .take(2)
   .collect {  todo(it) }
```

Comment: Relevant information would be what database library you’re using. The behavior of whatever flow it returns depends on how the library is designed. If you’re using Room, both your assumptions are correct, but your use of `flowOn` is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That is correct. `todo(it)` will be called every time a new record is added or updated in the database, as long as the flow is still active. Whenever there is a change in the database, the Flow returned by the listIncompleted() function emits values, causing the collect block to execute for each newly emitted value.
2. That's correct too. In Code B, the collect block will only be invoked twice and then the flow **will be cancelled**. `take()` operator is used when you need to limit the number of values that the flow will emit. So in your case the flow will be canceled after emitting 2 values.